# Securing GET call

Tags: php, ajax, http, get

I have a file, caller.php, which takes a GET URI that specifies a value to search the database for. The data is then returned in JSON format using php.

I want to protect caller.php so that it is only accessible from another page, get.php, using an AJAX call.

What is the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could check the session to see if the call is authorized or not. AJAX requests will send you the PHP session cookie. This assumes that caller.php is secured by some kind of user login system that uses sessions

Comment: +1 for "Ajax requests will send you the PHP session cookie" - this is usually the way to go

Comment: Would it be possible to put caller.php outside of the root directory?

Comment: You mean out of your web server's document root?

Comment: No. You need caller.php publicly accessible.. otherwise making a browser AJAX call won't obviously work.

Answer (score 9):

> I want to protect caller.php so that it is only accessible from another page, get.php, using an AJAX call.

You can't. An AJAX call can be easily faked, as can its origin.

There is no reliable way for you on server side to tell whether a call is an Ajax one or not, nor where it came from.

You need to secure your Ajax resource **the same way** you would secure a normal page - e.g. through an authorization system like a user login,  etcetera.

Without such an authorization system in place, you have to assume that everyone can access the URL.

Comment: I made this community Wiki because this question has at least two duplicates  that I have answered, but I can't find them right now. Ah well.

Comment: SSL as the transport does not actually apply in this case.

Comment: @Emil yeah, removed. I paid too much attention to the question title